# Регулярное выражение на определение и замену ссылок

Tags: регулярные-выражения, php

Как дописать функцию с регулярным выражением для определения ссылок и их замены таким образом, чтобы анкором был домен, например функция ниже делает из, например,

```
http://youtube.com/video123123
```

-

```
<a href='http://youtube.com/video123123'>http://youtube.com/video123123</a>
```

А мне нужно получить

```
<a href='http://youtube.com/video123123'>youtube.com</a>
```

-

```
preg_replace_callback(
'{
  (?:
    (\w+://)          # протокол с двумя слэшами
    |                 # - или -
    www\.             # просто начинается на www
  )
  [\w-]+(\.[\w-]+)*   # имя хоста
  \S*                 # URI (но БЕЗ кавычек)
  (?:                 # последний символ должен быть...
      (?<! [[:punct:]] )  # НЕ пунктуацией
    | (?<= [-/&+*]     )  # но допустимо окончание на -/&+*
  )
}xis',
create_function
(
    '$match',
    // Если нет протокола, добавляем его в начало строки.  
    '$href = !empty($match[1])? $match[0] : "http://".$match[0];
    // Формируем ссылку.
    return \'<a href="\'.$href.\'" target="_blank">\'.$match[0].\'</a>\';'
),
$text
)
```

Заранее спасибо.

Comment: сделайте var_dump($match[0]), скорее всего это match 1

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/293794/looking-for-a-regular-expression-to-extract-http-valid-uris-from-a-file

Comment: @ola_sh, Чтобы отформатировать код, выделите его мышью и нажмите на кнопку {} редактора.

Answer (score 1):

```
$result = preg_replace_callback("#
    ^
    (https?://) # группа (1) протокол
    (?:www\.)?
    ([\w-]+(\.[\w-]+)) # группа (2), то что вы хотите видеть в результате внутри тега <a/>
    *\S*(?:(?<! [[:punct:]])|(?<= [-/&+*]))$#", # без изменений, на ваше усмотрение
    create_function(
        '$matches',
        '$href = empty($matches[1]) ? "http://{$matches[0]}" : $matches[0];
        return "<a href=\"$href\">$matches[2]</a>";
    ), "http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php");
```

Кстати на мой взгляд можно не брать во внимание протокол, и без проверок существует или нет просто подставлять "http://". С "http", вполне нормально перенаправляет на "https".

Comment: Далеко не все сайты перенаправляют на HTTPS